# Displaying info in the eclipse console

Tags: c++, eclipse, console

I'm trying to compile a C++ project (Hello World) in windows 7 using Eclipse Helios. After creating the project the console shows me the next message:

Internal Builder is used for build               **
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -osrc\hello.o ..\src\hello.cpp
g++ -ohello.exe src\hello.o
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
warning: auto-importing has been activated without --enable-auto-import specified on the command line.

If I open the command line and execute: g++ hello.cpp -Wl,-enable-auto-import, I can generate the exe file and I can run it.

In eclipse after adding the argument "-Wl,--enable-auto-import" in the MinGW C++ Linker - Miscellaneous section, I didn't get any warning however, the console is always empty. Again, using the command line, if I move to the directory and execute the exe file generated by eclipse I get the expected result.

I know that Eclipse is compiling the cpp file properly but, why the eclipse console is not displaying the info? Is something missing in the configuration?

Sorry guys my stupid question.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an environment variable(s) and/or register paths problem.